# System.Collections.Generic.List MVC Error

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I want to view the table in `Edit.cshtml`
I was using the `Html.Action` to get the table from `SurveyQuestionController` but it shows the error as below:

> The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List``1[System.String]', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[SurveyTool.Models.SurveyQuestionModel]'.

Anything that i'm wrong??

Edit.cshtml:

```
@model SurveyTool.Models.SurveyModel
<div>
    <h2>Link</h2>
    @Html.Action("QuestionLink", "SurveyQuestion", new { id = Model.SurveyID })
</div>
```

SurveyQuestionController.cs:

```
public ActionResult QuestionLink(string SurveyID)
{
    var query = (from r in db.SurveyQuestionModels
                 where r.SurveyId == SurveyID
                 select r.QuestionLink).Distinct();

    return PartialView(query.ToList());
}
```

QuestionLink.cshtml :

```
 @model IEnumerable<SurveyTool.Models.SurveyQuestionModel>
 <br />     
 <table class="strip">
     @foreach (var item in Model)
     {
         <tr>
             <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelitem => item.QuestionLink)</td>
         </tr>
     }
 </table>
```

SurveyQuestionModel.cs :

```
namespace SurveyTool.Models
{
    public class SurveyQuestionModel
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string QuestionLink { get; set; } 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You query is selecting only the `QuestionLink` property of `SurveyQuestionModel` (by you use `select r.QuestionLink`) which is typeof `string`, hence your returning `List<string>` to the view, when the view expects `List<SurveyQuestionModel>`

Change the query to return a collection of `SurveyQuestionModel`

```
public ActionResult QuestionLink(string SurveyID)
{
    var query = (from r in db.SurveyQuestionModels
                 where r.SurveyId == SurveyID
                 select r);

    return PartialView(query.ToList());
}
```

or change the view so the model is `List<string>`

```
@model List<string>

@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    @Html.DisplayFor(modelitem => item)
}
```

Comment: Hi stephen, thanks for your answer, but i only want to select unique result. That's why im using distinct. Anyway to solve this?

Comment: Since your view is only displaying the `QuestionLink` value, then use the second option, otherwise you will need to modify your query

Comment: [This article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/535374/DistinctBy-in-Linq-Find-Distinct-object-by-Propert) gives you a few options for generating a collection based on the distinct value of just one property in a model.

Comment: Thanks alot stephen, i used 2nd option and it works! Very helpful info!